# How to process a request with squid externally?

Tags: proxy, squid

It is possible to catch a request that passes through squid proxy in order to analyze it with an external program?

I have an application that is used in about 400 workstations. I don't have access to any config or source code of this application, but I have access to squid that proxies the requests to it.

Business rules demand that users only can open a single session at any time, but I'he noticed that the users open various sessions simultaneously.

So, I'm considering to write a python (or php) script to analyze the requests to the server and check if a session is already open and if so, block it.

Comment: if you would do so within EU you will get busted - however, try to use the [Squid manual](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/client_ip_max_connections/)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm not from EU, so for now that strategy is not a problem. Any way, I don't think the `client_ip_max_connections` will help because I need to check if the session exists in a database before I decide to block it.

Comment: you said, you want to limit hhhe connections per ip, that's what it does. else, you need to update the question and be more specific. IMHO it feels like a [x and y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)